# Creating columns from counts in pyhton

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataset

```
 Manager_Name     Hire_Type      Person_Hired    Status 
    Adam             FT             James        Pending
    Adam             PT             Emily        Approved
    Ben              FT             Paul         Approved 
    Ben              FT             Sarah        Approved
```

I need to create two columns with the counts by `Manager_Name`
of how many pending and approved hires each manager has.

Desired output:

```
     Manager_Name    Approvals     Pending
        Adam             1            1
        Ben              2            0
```

Thank you

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['Manager_Name'], df['Status'])`

Comment: Will you please provide the code you've written so far in attempt to solve this issue?